# couldn't find the working irc chat channel for rails

Tags: irc

I have been struggling a lot to find the working chat channel for rails. I tried on the following url

```
http://irc.lc/freenode/rails
```

and when i try to connect. It gives me the following error:

```
You've been forwarded to ##namespace by attempting to join a channel which doesn't exist on freenode.  This may be because the channel has moved to the correct namespace or off the network.  Please see http://freenode.net/policy.shtml#channelnaming for our channel naming policy.
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use a real IRC client and join #ruby or #rubyonrails on freenode. Limechat does the trick. Also make sure you have a verified account on Freenode.

Comment: but for this i need to download the client and i don't want that. Could you please tell me some online chat channel where i can chat in real time.

Comment: https://webchat.freenode.net/ works but I would seriously consider using a terminal based or desktop client.